# Generate a function which has a decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I know that I can generate functions with lambda expressions or `setattr`, but is there a way to generate functions at runtime that have decorators? For example create `@property` and `@<name>.setter` functions at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, given that

```
@decorator(config)
def function(args):
    # ...
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
def function(args):
    # ...
function = decorator(config)(function)
```

I'm sure you can figure out the rest. :)